# How can I use onecolumn and twocolmn text in different pages in the same document?

Tags: two-column, geometry

I am trying to use `onecolumn` and `twocolumn`, from the [`geometry` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) in the same document simultaneously (that is, different styles in different pages).

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: use `\onecolumn` or `\twocolumn` to switch

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `multicols` environment (from `multicol`, see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol)) and change document's layout in-place

[image: example]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
%%% Added only for dummy texts and can be removed
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%%% END

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ctitle{O{l}m}{%
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}#1}{\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{#2}}}}


\begin{document}
\section{One-column layout}
\kant[1]

\begin{multicols}{3}[\section{Mult-icolumn layout}]
  \kant[2]
\end{multicols}
\kant[3][1-2]

\section{One-column layout}
\kant[4]
\end{document}
```